# Access the text of a button in another file

Tags: python, button, tkinter, import

In one file I have

```
def ang_conv():
    if ang['text']=='DEG':
        ang.config(text='RAD')

     elif ang['text']=='RAD':
        ang.config(text='DEG')

ang=ttk.Button(text='RAD',width=6, command=ang_conv)
ang.grid(column=0,row=4)
```

And in another file I have

```
def sin(x):

    #returns Taylor's sine expression where n = 0,1,2,3...
    def t_exp(n):     
        return (-1)**n * (x**(2*n+1)) / fact(2*n+1)

    #Summing Taylor series

    n,sum=0,0
    while abs(t_exp(n))>= 1.0e-8:
        sum+=t_exp(n)
        n+=1
    return sum
```

I want to enter an if block in sine, that's like: if ang button's text is DEG, return sum*57.2958

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `sine_file.py`:

```
import another_file
...
def sin(x):
    ...
    if another_file.ang['text'] == 'DEG':
        pass
```

Though, I believe it should be the GUI script, `one_file.py` that drives the App, not the other way around.